# If I divide 100/40 in python how can I get value of 5/2 without python performing true division or decimal division

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, division

If I divide 100/40 in python how can I get value of 5/2 without python performing true division or decimal division
Eg:

1. If I divide 100 by 20 i need value of 5/1 in python not simply 5 similarly for 100 by 40 i need to get a value of 5/2 not 2.5 and for 100/60 value 5/3 how can i get that in python.

Comment: the `fractions` module

Comment: ..or use SymPy.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [the `fractions` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#module-fractions)

```
In [1]: from fractions import Fraction

In [2]: Fraction(100, 40)
Out[2]: Fraction(5, 2)
```

or [the `sympy` (Symbolic Python) module](https://www.sympy.org/)

```
In [3]: from sympy import Rational

In [4]: Rational(100, 40)
Out[4]: 5/2
```

The `sympy` module is much more complex and opens to you a world of symbolic computations, the `fractions` module loads immediately and does JUST what you asked for.
The choice is yours…

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [fractions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) module:

```
import fractions

f = fractions.Fraction(100, 40)

print(f'{f.numerator}/{f.denominator}')
```

Result:

```
5/2
```